# having both scrolling and drawing

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, drawing, uigesturerecognizer

I created a drawing application. Since I use drawing on a large image I also need to have scrolling as well, but when I implemented scrolling, the drawing did not work any more.

I think there is a conflict on the *touch event* between drawing and scrolling.

I am thinking to do scrolling with two finger and drawing with one finger, but I could not find out how to implement it. I appreciate if any one could help me to fix this problem.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroller.contentSize=temp.frame.size;
    toggledrawandscroll=false;


}
- (IBAction)changescrollstatues:(id)sender {
   if(toggledrawandscroll){
    //if draw is enable,disable it
    toggledrawandscroll =false;
    scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scroller.canCancelContentTouches=YES;
    scroller.contentSize=temp.frame.size;
}
else{

    toggledrawandscroll =true;
    scroller.scrollEnabled=NO;
    scroller.canCancelContentTouches=NO;

}
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        mouseSwiped = NO;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        }

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        //initial setting for touch point
        mouseSwiped = YES;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        //set the concext
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [temp.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);


        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        //drawing setting
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),red, green, blue, 1);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        temp.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        lastPoint = currentPoint;

}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
           if(!mouseSwiped) {

            //initial seting
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [temp.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            temp.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a toggle to enable scrolling?  If that is the case your *changesscrollstatues* method never enables the scroll and never sets your boolean to *YES*.  Your scroller is always enabled so the touch event won't get captured.

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I have changed my code but only scrolling still works!

Comment: If that wasn't the issue you could try to set *scroller.canCancelContentTouches* appropriately.  If you set it to *YES* then scroll events will be caught.  If *NO* then your content view will track your touch events.

Comment: I also have tried scroller.canCancelContect as you can see in my updated code, but only the scrolling worked well! @dragonflyesque